# Thymeleaf URL construction

Tags: url, uri, thymeleaf

Is there any special tool in `Thymeleaf` to construct URLs by adding/removing/replacing parameters?
For example, I need to make a request to the same page but adding one additional parameter "p=1" into the request. So that:

```
'/foo?a=b' becomes '/foo?a=b&p=1' // addition
'/foo?p=0' becomes '/foo?p=1'     // replacing
```

`@{}` doesn't seem to be helpful here.
I would imagine something like the following to exist:
`@{#currentUri(*, p=1, !q)}`, where '*' is for all existing params, 'p=1' means add/replace and '!' means excluding.

Does `Thymeleaf` have anything like that or any other syntax for flexible URL construction?

Comment: Please look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68212965/3271406). It should fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `Thymeleaf` does not provide any such utility.

But, since it leverages `Spring EL` it is fairly easy to write a helper class with a set of utility methods and make it available for the expressions to call those methods. Syntactically it can look very close to the imaginary example from the question: `@{#currentUri("*", "p=1", "!q")}`

Answer (score 1):

I know its a while ago when you asked this question, anyhow.

It seems that your are looking for the httpServeltRequest.requestURI

```
<a th:href="@{${'~' + #httpServletRequest.requestURI}(lang=${language})}" th:text="#{${'Language.' + lang}}"><span>Switch to English</span></a>
```

And with the `#httpServletRequest.QueryString` you can get all the parameters given in the current url. Unfortunatly I'm not shure if you can exclude any parameters.

Source: http://forum.thymeleaf.org/How-to-link-to-current-page-and-exchange-parameter-td4024870.html

Comment: `queryString` is just a string and it would be tricky to reconstruct the URL with modifications as a 1-line expression. It would require to brake the query string into keys and values and then reconstruct URL param by param.