# Thymeleaf: add parameter to current url

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, url-parameters

I'm at

```
http://example.com/some/page?p1=11
```

and I want to add a parameter to current url without having to redefine it:

```
http://example.com/some/page?p1=11&p2=32
```

with something like:

```
<a th:href="@{?(p2=32)}">Click here</a>
```

but the above code return `http://example.com/some/page?&p2=32` (removes the `p1` parameter).

How can I do it using **Thymeleaf**?

Comment: Is there really still no proper way to handle this (as of spring 2016)?

Answer (score 30):

You can use URI builder, directly from Thymeleaf.

```
<span th:with="urlBuilder=${T(org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder).fromCurrentRequest()}"
      th:text="${urlBuilder.replaceQueryParam('p2', '32').toUriString()}">
</span>
```

For URL `http://example.com/some/page?p1=11` prints out:

```
http://example.com/some/page?p1=11&p2=32
```

**Explained:**

- SpEL [`T` operator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-types) is used for accessing `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` type.
- An instance created by factory method `fromCurrentRequest` is saved to `urlBuilder` variable.
- A param is added or replaced in the query string by `replaceQueryParam` method, and then the URL is built.

**Pros:**

- Safe solution.
- No trailing `?` in case of empty query string.
- No extra bean in Spring context.

**Cons:**

- It is quite verbose.

! Be aware that solution above creates one instance of the builder. This means that the builder cannot be reused because it still modifies an original URL. For multiple URLs on a page you have to create multiple builders, like this:

```
<span th:with="urlBuilder=${T(org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder)}">
    <span th:text="${urlBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().replaceQueryParam('p2', 'whatever').toUriString()}"></span>
    <span th:text="${urlBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().replaceQueryParam('p3', 'whatever').toUriString()}"></span>
    <span th:text="${urlBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().replaceQueryParam('p4', 'whatever').toUriString()}"></span>
</span>
```

For `http://example.com/some/page` prints:

```
http://example.com/some/page?p2=whatever 
http://example.com/some/page?p3=whatever     
http://example.com/some/page?p4=whatever
```

Comment: For anyone in the future, you can also replace multiple parameter with the use of multiple `replaceQueryParam` like this `${urlBuilder.replaceQueryParam('page', current).replaceQueryParam('size', page.size).toUriString()`

Comment: how can i set 'p4' to 'two,values' ?  instead of &p4=two,values it keeps creating two parameters like &p4=two&p4=values

Comment: figured it out, i just passed it as first argument of a list like {'two,values'}

Comment: You need `.build().toUriString()` to avoid `p=%25` to be encoded again as `p=%2525`

Comment: No longer works in Thymeleaf version 3.1.2

Answer (score 20):

The easiest solution is concatenating "requestURI" and "queryString".
Here is example:

```
<div th:with="currentUrl=(${#httpServletRequest.requestURI + '?' + #strings.defaultString(#httpServletRequest.queryString, '')})">
   <a th:href="@{${currentUrl}(myparam=test)}">click here</a>
</div>
```

Result for "http://localhost:8080/some-page?param1=1":

```
 http://localhost:8080/some-page?param1=1&myparam=test
```

Result for "http://localhost:8080/some-page":

```
 http://localhost:8080/some-page?&myparam=test
```

Drawback:
Thymeleaf doesn't overwrite parameters - only adds parameters to URL. So if you user click once again to that URL, the result will be:

```
http://localhost:8080/some-page?param1=1&myparam=test&myparam=test
```

References: 
http://forum.thymeleaf.org/How-to-link-to-current-page-and-exchange-parameter-td4024870.html

EDIT:

Here is some workaround, which removes parameter "myparam" from the URL:

```
<div th:with="currentUrl=(${@currentUrlWithoutParam.apply('myparam')})">
    <a th:href="@{${currentUrl}(myparam=test)}">click here</a>
</div>
```

Next in Spring configuration:

```
@Bean
public Function<String, String> currentUrlWithoutParam() {
    return param ->   ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().replaceQueryParam(param).toUriString();
}
```

For more "global" solution, I would try extending processor for attribute "th:href" or creating my own attribute. I'm not a thymeleaf expert, just facing similar problem.

Comment: Workaround for drawback is to create base url without parameter we want to add.

Comment: In the first case: be sure to use `${#httpServletRequest.requestURI + '?' + #strings.defaultString(#httpServletRequest.queryString, '')}` instead, in order to avoid appending `null` to your URL.

Comment: Thanks for notice that "queryString" could be null. Link to [javadoc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString()).

Answer (score 3):

```
th:href="@{/your/link?parameter=__${appendParameter}__}"
```

Comment: Note that the `__` (double underscore) are needed for this to work, these will not appear in the result

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#using-expressions-in-urls) you can specify *all* parameters

```
th:href="@{http://example.com/some/page(p1=11,p2=32)}"
```

You can use expressions to get values:

```
th:href="@{http://example.com/some/page(p1=11,p2=${someid})}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34800435/3271406) from [Raf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5770135/raf) I ended up with this solution:

```
@Bean
public BiFunction<String, String, String> replaceOrAddParam() {
  return (paramName, newValue) -> ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
        .replaceQueryParam(paramName, newValue)
        .toUriString();
}
```

```
<a th:href="${@replaceOrAddParam.apply('myParamName', 'myNewValue')}">Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you, even in Unicode:

```
 <ul class="pagination">
                <li th:if="${currentPage > 1}"><a th:href="'/search?key=' + ${param.key[0]} + '&amp;page=' +   ${currentPage-1}">Previous</a></li>

                      <li th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence( 1, total+1)}" th:class="${i==currentPage}?active:''">
                            <a th:href="'/search?key=' + ${param.key[0]} + '&amp;page=' +   ${i}" th:inline="text">
                            [[${i}]] <span  class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                            </a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a th:if="${total + 1 > currentPage}" th:href="'/search?key=' + ${param.key[0]} + '&amp;page=' +   ${currentPage+1}">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
```