# How to replace URL parameters in a thymeleaf link?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have an existing URL with get parameters. On a button click, I want to change one specific URL parameter, but retain the others. Is that possible?

Thymeleaf template:

```
<a th:href="@{/order/details(id=3)}">
```

Results in:

```
<a href="/order/details?id=3">
```

What if I want to

- preserve other parameters in the URL
- override the `id` parameter?

Desired result of the thymeleaf template above:

```
localhost:8080/order/details?name=test&id=3
```

Preferably without javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by "on a button click"? Will send request to server? or just directly want to change the params in links?

Comment: Both. I have a  <form method="get" href="...">`, thus on click the url changes (automatically) and calls the backend service url.

Comment: So, that should be done using JS. Not by thymeleaf

Comment: Please look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68212965/3271406). It should fit your needs.

Answer (score 6):

Even though it's an older question, I hope this could still help:

```
<a th:href="@{${urlBuilder.replaceQueryParam('id', 3).build().toUriString()}}" th:with="urlBuilder=${T(org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder).fromCurrentRequest()}">
```

This builds a complete URI string, including the HTTP(S) part. So if you use (for example) a load balancer for your web applications and it doesn't forward https requests directly, you will get a wrong URI string. In this case, you have to do it like [Zico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1125284/zico) wrote: Set the baseUrl in the controller and bind it to the template.
You could also get the query string from the current request: `request.getQueryString()` or use the `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` class in your controller.

---

**Edit**

You can apply `.scheme('https')` to `urlBuilder` (`@{${urlBuilder.replaceQueryParam('id', 3).scheme('https').build().toUriString()}}`). E.g. you can create a method in your controller which gets the `X-Forwarded-Proto` from your load balancer.

Check example #27 from here: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder

Answer (score 2):

**Set the baseURL from controller then bind baseURL to template**

**In Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String home(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest req) {
  String baseUrl = req.getScheme() + "://" + req.getServerName() + ":" + req.getServerPort() + req.getContextPath();
  ....
  model.addAttribute("baseUrl", baseUrl);
  model.addAttribute("name", name);
  .....
```

**In Template:**

```
<a th:href="@{__${baseUrl}__/order/details(name=${name},id=3)}">
```

Comment: Of course I want to retain any existing query parameters. Just override them at will.

Comment: Well, as written in the initial question: "preserve other parameters in the URL"

Comment: sorry i missed it