# Add language part into existing url after changing Language in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf

I have a problem about adding the language part into the existing URL after changing Language in Spring Boot

Here is my URL listing all brands by name in ascending order.

```
admin/brands/page/1?sortField=name&sortDir=asc
```

When I change the language, the URL has occured as shown below.

```
admin/brands/page/1?lang=fr
```

Here is my language change code snippets in thymeleaf shown below.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{?lang=en}">
        <img th:src="@{/images/english.png}" width="30">
    </a>
</li>
                
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{?lang=fr}">
        <img th:src="@{/images/french.png}" width="30">
    </a>
</li>
```

I want to get this url `admin/brands/page/1?sortField=name&sortDir=asc&lang=fr`

How can I do that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623405/thymeleaf-add-parameter-to-current-url

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I found this way, is it right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thymeleaf: add parameter to current url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623405/thymeleaf-add-parameter-to-current-url)

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Yeah. I answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution shown below.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" 
       th:with="urlBuilder=${T(org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder).fromCurrentRequest()}"
       th:href="${urlBuilder.replaceQueryParam('lang', 'en').toUriString()}">
        <img th:src="@{/images/english.png}" width="30">
    </a>
</li>
                
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" 
       th:with="urlBuilder=${T(org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder).fromCurrentRequest()}"
       th:href="${urlBuilder.replaceQueryParam('lang', 'tr').toUriString()}">
         <img th:src="@{/images/turkish.png}" width="30">
    </a>
</li>
```